# python 1:1 stratified sampling per each group

Tags: python, pandas, multisampling, subsampling

How can a 1:1 stratified sampling be performed in python?

Assume the Pandas Dataframe `df` to be heavily imbalanced. It contains a binary group and multiple columns of categorical sub groups.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5], 'group':[0,1,0,1,0], 'sub_category_1':[1,2,2,1,1], 'sub_category_2':[1,2,2,1,1], 'value':[1,2,3,1,2]})
display(df)
display(df[df.group == 1])
display(df[df.group == 0])
df.group.value_counts()
```

For each member of the main `group==1` I need to find a single match of `group==0` with.

A `StratifiedShuffleSplit` from scikit-learn will only return a random portion of data, not a 1:1 match.

Comment: In your input example there are not common values between sub_category_2 between group 1 and group 0. Well there is just one.

Comment: Well you cannot get the same distribution as the group 1, because there are no elements with value 2 on the sub_category_2 just adding one more row will be fine.

Comment: Added one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you could use [np.random.permutation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'group': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'sub_category_1': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1],
                   'sub_category_2': [1, 2, 2, 1, 1], 'value': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]})

# create new column with an identifier for a combination of categories
columns = ['sub_category_1', 'sub_category_2']
labels = df.loc[:, columns].apply(lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x.values)), axis=1)
values, keys = pd.factorize(labels)
df['label'] = labels.map(dict(zip(keys, values)))

# build distribution of sub-categories combinations
distribution = df[df.group == 1].label.value_counts().to_dict()

# select from group 0 only those rows that are in the same sub-categories combinations
mask = (df.group == 0) & (df.label.isin(distribution))

# do random sampling
selected = np.ravel([np.random.permutation(group.index)[:distribution[name]] for name, group in df.loc[mask].groupby(['label'])])

# display result
result = df.drop('label', axis=1).iloc[selected]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
   group  id  sub_category_1  sub_category_2  value
4      0   5               1               1      2
2      0   3               2               2      3
```

Note that this solution assumes the size of the each possible sub_category combination of `group 1` is less than the size of the corresponding sub-group in `group 0`. A more robust version involves using [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) with replacement:

```
selected = np.ravel([np.random.choice(group.index, distribution[name], replace=True) for name, group in df.loc[mask].groupby(['label'])])
```

The version with choice does not have the same assumption as the one with permutation, although it requires at least one element for each sub-category combination.

Comment: Your assumption of 1 < 0 is fine. However, you only calculate a random subsample for group 0. I instead need to also consider all the sub categories. I initially concatenated all columns i.e. `group_sub_category_1_sub_category_2` to generate new classes but as mentioned got stuck with the `StratifiedShuffleSplit `.

Comment: Indeed. For both `sub_category_1` and `sub_category_2` (in fact for the real dataset it is about 10 columns).

Comment: This should be the case as well. But if possible it would be great if it is resilient enough to also handle the case if they are equal or smaller. But the first case would already be great.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Updated the answer!