# spark efficient distribution pairing to compare cohorts

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, matching, multisampling, subsampling

How can I efficiently compare matched cohorts in spark?

In python for each observation of the minority class in a highly imbalanced dataset sampling `k` observations from the majority class can be implemented in a fairly straightforward way (i.e. matching a healthy person for each sick person by age and gender):

[Improve performance calculating a random sample matching specific conditions in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097019/improve-performance-calculating-a-random-sample-matching-specific-conditions-in/56099329#56099329) or [python 1:1 stratified sampling per each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653317/python-11-stratified-sampling-per-each-group)

But how can this be scaled out in spark? Naively, a self-join with filter should work. But this fails due to too many tuples being generated.

Are there smarter strategies? Maybe some smart hashing like LSH?

Comment: May be this https://sparkhub.databricks.com/video/real-time-fuzzy-matching-with-spark-and-elastic-search/